# how to import multiple version of aws_secretsmanager_secret_version into terraform state?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-secrets-manager

I have CI CD pipeline where I was trying to import 2 versions into `aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.example` resource as shown below,

```
import {
  to = aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.example
  id = "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:123456789012:secret:example-123456|xxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxx"
}

import {
  to = aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.example
  id = "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:123456789012:secret:example-123456|yyyyy-yyyyyyy-yyyyyyy-yyyyy"
}
```

Error:

> │ Error: Duplicate import configuration for "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.example"
> │
> │   on main.tf line 6:
> │   6: import {
> │
> │ An import block for the resource
> │ "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.example"
> │ was already declared at main.tf:1,1-7. A resource can have only one import
> │ block.

Comment: Can you add the resource block to the question as well?

Comment: Thanks @MarkoE Your comment help me realise that I can create 2 version resources and add 2 import blocks pointing to those resources. You can post it as answer. I will accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two versions can be imported into two different resource. For example, the first one can be called `version_x` and the second one `version_y`:

```
import {
  to = aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.version_x
  id = "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:123456789012:secret:example-123456|xxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxx"
}

import {
  to = aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.version_y
  id = "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:123456789012:secret:example-123456|yyyyy-yyyyyyy-yyyyyyy-yyyyy"
}
```

[Import block](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/import#import-multiple-instances-with-for_each) also allows using `for_each`, so you could try with that as well instead of having two resource blocks. An example:

```
locals {
  secret_versions = {
    "version_x" = "xxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxx"
    "version_y" = "yyyyy-yyyyyyy-yyyyyyy-yyyyy"
  }
}

import {
  for_each = local.secret_versions
  to       = aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.example[each.key]
  id       = "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:123456789012:secret:example-123456|${each.value}"
}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "example" {
  for_each = local.secret_versions
  .
  .
  .
}
```

It should work with terraform versions >=1.7.x.

Comment: Can you please show an example of using `for_each`?